# Derived from two Bases - Delete vector **strange** problem

Tags: c++

I am hours trying to figurate out where is the problem, but it seems so strange.

I rewrote my problem in an easier way to understand.

When it gets to the line where it says delete, the debbug makes a breakpoint.

Ps. Intresting to note that, if we take int b1 and move it to Base2 it works.

Base1:

```
#pragma once
class Base1
{
public:
    Base1();
    ~Base1();
    int b1;
};
```

Base2.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
class Derived;
class Base2
{
public:
    Base2();
    ~Base2();
    std::vector <std::vector <Base2*>> vec;
    void doSomething(Derived& d);
};
```

Base2.cpp:

```
#include "Base2.h"
#include "Derived.h"


Base2::Base2()
{
    //the numbers 1 and 5 does not really metter
    vec.resize(1);
    vec[0].resize(5);
}


Base2::~Base2()
{
}

void Base2::doSomething(Derived& d)
{
    vec[0][d.b1] = new Derived();
    delete vec[0][d.b1];
}
```

Derived:

```
#pragma once
#include "Base1.h"
#include "Base2.h"
class Derived : public Base1, public Base2
{
public:
    Derived();
    ~Derived();
};
```

main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Derived.h"

int main()
{
    Derived d;
    d.b1 = 1;
    d.doSomething(d);
}
```

Comment: I'd advise you to learn about smart pointers; `std::unique_ptr`, `std::shared_ptr` & `std::weak_ptr` (and friends; `std::make_unique`, `std::make_shared`) and stop using manual memory management (raw `new` and `delete`).

Comment: Undefined behaviour since `Base2` does not have a virtual destructor.   You could achieve the same (undefined behaviour, which may or may not result in a runtime error) with `Base2 * p = new Derived;  delete p;`.   The fact it happens to work by moving `int b1` to `Base2` is happenstance - the behaviour is still undefined.

Comment: Thanks guys. So why if move int b1 to Base2 it works? And do I need a Virtual for Base1? or why not? (I will take a look on the duplicate question, it may have an answer there as well - (edited:) it does not have since we are talking about two Bases).

Comment: Simply put: [undefined behavior is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2397984/5470596). It's a good read too ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Base2` lacks a virtual destructor.

Deleting a derived object via a pointer to it's base, if that base doesn't have a virtual destructor, leads to undefined behavior.

---

Usually this kind of UB only leads to missing destructor calls (and thus memory/resource leaks), but in this case, since multiple inheritance is involved, the situation is different.

When you convert a pointer returned by `new Derived()` to `Base2 *`, the numerical value of the pointer *changes* (due to multiple inheritance).

After `delete` calls `~Base2()`, it subsequently passes the pointer to a memory deallocation function.
The deallocation function expects the same address that was returned by `new`, which is the address of an entire `Derived` instance. Instead it gets an address of `Base2` subobject, which is *different* (again, due to multiple inheritance).

This is no different from any other *"attept to `delete` a pointer that wasn't returned by `new`"* situation, and usually results in a crash.

If `Base2` had a virtual destructor, the pointer would be adjusted to point to the entire instance of `Derived` before deallocation.

Comment: It was a very helpful answer. Thank you!